# Is it possible to store a method in Android shared preference

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

How to store a user defined method in shared preferences in android and how to load the data from that method in another activity

Comment: a method - no. Only data can be stored. What are you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: That would be highly unusual, but not necessarily impossible - it translates to the dynamic class loading on android series of questions.

Comment: private void storeArray(ToggleButton bt,int id)
    {
   if(bt.isChecked())
   {
     try
     {
      
      toggleBtnArray[id]=true;
      Log.e("ARRAY", "e "+toggleBtnArray[id]);
      
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
      Log.e("ArrayErr",e.toString());
     }
     
   }
   
 }

Comment: It sounds like whatever you're trying to do can be done more easily and simply. What do you mean, load the data from the method?

Comment: Yoc can only store data, not methods, classes, etc

Comment: @weston :Hi,I hav a method called storeArray ,in the method there is an array called toggleBtnArray[15] ,it stores the states of some toggle buttons (true/false).Whenever the user clicks on the button it stores the corresponding btn location as true,the method storeArray(int,int)is parametrised ,the method storeArray is called in another method getInfo it passes the clickd toggle button's object and its "id" to storeArray as parameter ,thus all the states are saved in the array storeArray..I want to store  the method storeArray in spreference so i can acces it in another activity .